# Where does j get its value in selection sort? Basic Q, Python 3

Tags: sorting, selection, trace

So I'm tracing through the code below.
I'm confused as to where j gets its value. It gets iterated by 1 at the for loop but I'm blanking on why. i is getting the +1, not j?

I think I'm just totally burnt out and missing something suuuper obvious lol!

```
def selection_sort(a):

    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n-1):
        min = i
        for j in range(i + 1,n):
            if (a[j] < a[min]):
                min = j
        if (min != i):
            a[i], a[min] = a[min], a[i] # swap
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_list = ['cat', 'pig', 'cow', 'dog', 'sheep', 'chicken']
    print(selection_sort(test_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

`for j in range(i + 1,n)` means *assign, in succession, the values from i+1 up to (but not including) n*.